# Python IF statement can't recognize else:

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to verify if a row is displayed or not. I am using python and Selenium. Here is what I have tried so far

```
    try:
        row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(<row6>).is_displayed()
        if row is False:
            print("button is not displayed. Test is passed")
        else:
            do stuff
    except:
        NoSuchElementException
```

I am trying to achieve the following:
Page #1 will only display a button if Page #2 has row < 6.

I still have logic to write for the condition -> if row is False: . However, it should atleast print the string if it is false.

At the moment, the else: in my code is not working. There is no error displays but try: exits at the NoSuchElementException.

**UPDATE:** I have also tried the following code where I verify if button is displayed on page #1,  go to the page #2 and validate if row6 is present. That works if button is displayed. If button is not displayed, it throws an error :NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:

```
    try:
        button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(PATH)
        if button.is_displayed():
            do stuff
            row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(<row6>)
            if row.is_displayed():
                do stuff
            else:
                do stuff
    except:
        button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("PATH").is_displayed()
        if button is False:
            print("button is hidden. Test is passed")
```

Any suggestion on how I can make this work??

Comment: Do you expect something to loop? `if` doesn't start a loop.

Comment: Yes. So if row is False: -> button is not displayed , if row is True, button is displayed. Either way, test is valid.

Comment: Im very confused by your question and what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: There is a button that is hidden if row < 6. I am trying to verify if the button is displayed or not. In order for me to validate that, the entire row in a different page needs to be displayed OR the button in different page is hidden. I hope I am explaining this right.

Comment: If the element `row` does not exist, one would think that the exception would be thrown right at `row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath()`. Maybe it's only throwing an exception once you try to access it. Probably need to put it in its own `try-except` block.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's no hidden `row6` to be found and an exception is raised.

The syntax of your except is wrong: as it is, it will catch all exceptions and then just do nothing with the `NoSuchElementException` object.

Did you mean:

```
except NoSuchElementException:
    #do something when no row6 found
```

Comment: Thanks for the syntax correction. However, if you check in my code, variable`row`is saved inside the `try` statement. If it does not exists and added under `except:`, selenium displays 3 different errors 1) InvalidSelectorException: 2)InvalidSelectorError: 3)SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression. Unfortunately, it does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Selenium, but it sounds like there may be multiple exceptions here, not all of the same type, and not where you might expect them to happen. For instance, everything is fine when `row.is_displayed()` evaluates to `True`, but an exception is thrown otherwise - This indicates to me that `row` might be `None` or some other unexpected result. I've taken a cursory look at the [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=find_element_by_xpath#webdriver-api) but I couldn't see right away.

Anyway - to debug this, try putting different sections of your code into `try-except` blocks:

```
try:
    button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(PATH)
    if button.is_displayed():
        do stuff
        try: 
            row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(<row6>)
        except:  # <-- Better if you test against a specific Exception!
            print(" something is wrong with row! ")
        try:
            if row.is_displayed():
                do stuff
            else:
                do stuff
        except:  # <-- Better if you test against a specific Exception!
            print( " something is wrong with using row!" )
except:  # <-- Better if you test against a specific Exception!
    button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("PATH").is_displayed()
    if button is False:
        print("button is hidden. Test is passed")
```

Also, try to put a minimum amount of code inside each `try-except`, so that you know where the exception is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am researching the solution for this issue online. It seems like a very common issue with verifying the 'invisibility' of an element in Selenium.